# Count how many customers have ordered 3 or more times in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a data source added in Google Data Studio which is similar to the following:

| Order ID | Date | Customer ID | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 36252 | 1/1/2021 12:25:00 | 6565 | $64.00 |
| 16805 | 2/1/2020 13:55:00 | 694 | $32.00 |
| 16802 | 2/1/2020 13:50:00 | 694 | $33.00 |
| 16798 | 2/1/2020 12:13:00 | 54 | $30.00 |
| 16790 | 2/1/2020 10:51:00 | 1515 | $23.00 |
| 16784 | 2/1/2020 10:48:00 | 386 | $34.00 |
| 16782 | 2/1/2020 10:03:00 | 2968 | $30.00 |
| 16793 | 2/1/2020 9:33:00 | 1197 | $124.00 |
| 16778 | 2/1/2020 8:36:00 | 17 | $25.00 |
| 16766 | 2/1/2020 7:48:00 | 250 | $30.00 |
| 16760 | 2/1/2020 5:06:00 | 2282 | $28.00 |
| 37176 | 2/1/2021 14:12:00 | 6803 | $33.00 |
| 37175 | 2/1/2021 13:55:00 | 4916 | $37.00 |

I need to calculate how many Customers have placed 2 or more orders but haven't found a way to do this.

I tried creating a calculated field with this formula:

```
CASE
  WHEN COUNT(Customer ID)>1 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

but I can't find a way to total this calculated field. I get the error:

> Re-aggregating metrics is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group those data first to be able to count based on `Customer ID`.

Put `Customer ID` as dimension and `Order ID` as metric and you will be able to calculate with your function then show the summary to get the number of customers with order > 2

or if what I wrote here is not what you're expecting and you need to re-agrregate a field, you can use blend data to reaggregate an aggregated field with `Customer ID` as join key and add `Order ID` from both table.

Source:
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9429470